Spring cloud kafka Produce multiple KStream records with different key after enriching input KStream
I have a requirement where I need produce multiple records with different key using spring cloud kafka binders.
@Getter 
@Setter 
public class Transaction {     
  private String paymentRef;     
  private String List<AccountDetails> accounts; 
}  
@Getter
@Setter
public class AccountDetails {     
   private String accountId;     
   private String accountHolderName; 
}

Below is my Input
{
  "paymentRef":"12345", 
  "accounts": [{
    "accountId": "AB12345",
    "accountHolderName": "Dietrich Fritzi"
   }, {
    "accountId": "CD98741",
    "accountHolderName": "Wibke Elisabeth"
   }]
}

My expected output will be:
Key :: 12345-AB12345, Value :: {
  "paymentRef":"12345", 
  "accounts": [{
    "accountId": "AB12345",
    "accountHolderName": "Dietrich Fritzi"
   }, {
    "accountId": "CD98741",
    "accountHolderName": "Wibke Elisabeth"
   }]
}

Key :: 12345-CD98741, Value :: {
  "paymentRef":"12345", 
  "accounts": [{
    "accountId": "AB12345",
    "accountHolderName": "Dietrich Fritzi"
   }, {
    "accountId": "CD98741",
    "accountHolderName": "Wibke Elisabeth"
   }]
}

Can anyone please help me to write Function, As of now I have
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Transaction>, List<KStream<String, Transaction>>> accountTransaction() {
return transaction -> transaction
        .peek((key, value) -> log.info("Incoming Transaction, Key :: [{}] Value :: [{}]", key, value))
        .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getPaymentReference() + "-" + value.getAccounts().stream().findFirst().map(AccountDetails::getAccountId).orElse("NO_VALUE"), value))
        .peek((key, value) -> log.info("Outgoing Transaction, key :: {} Value :: {}", key, value));
}

The problem with this function it generate only one ouput value, I need to to generate for output for all the AccountDetails within the Transaction.

Have you tried flatMap operator or use the Processor API?

Thanks @OneCricketeer, flatMap solve my One-To-Many transformation.
